# React Native Mapbox GL give UserLocation custom position

Tags: react-native, mapbox, mapbox-gl

react-native-mapbox-gl provides a UserLocation component to display the location of the user via builtin Geolocation tracking: https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/docs/UserLocation.md

However I would like to leverage all the animation, rendering and bearing aspects, etc. of this component BUT with my own position data (at least longitude, latitude and heading/bearing).

I do not see this currently as possible or mentioned in the documentation of their repo.
Is it possible?

It seems to be possible in the underlying Android documentation:
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/api/9.6.1/index.html / LocationComponent:

```
...You can also push location updates to the component without any internal engine management.
To achieve that, use activateLocationComponent(Context, Style, boolean) with false.
No engine is going to be initialized and you can push location updates with forceLocationUpdate(Location).
...
```

Comment: Possibly downvoted downvoted bc/ "does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful"

1. "Does not show any research effort":
I have not found it possible/mentioned in the documentation of react-native-mapbox-gl, I looked at their docs, maybe I am missing it...
2. "It is unclear": If it is pls provide what you find unclear so I can clarify
3. "Or not useful": That's a surprisingly suggestive conclusion, please clarify how it's not useful to anyone (INCLUDING me); I'm obviously trying to determine how to do this in React Native. I even pointed out it's possible in Android

Comment: Did you manage to come up with a solution for this?

Comment: @ChristianMoen
The answer I posted is still the current solution I am using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it seems there is no props or API for this in the docs so I am doing what should be safe to do: extend the UserLocation component:

```
export default class CustomUserLocation extends UserLocation {
  static defaultProps = {
    ...UserLocation.defaultProps,
    <your custom props here>
  }

  async componentDidUpdate (prevProps) {
    await UserLocation.prototype.componentDidUpdate.call(this, prevProps)
    ...<checks for your custom props here>
  }

  // !! this is the key method to override
  _onLocationUpdate (location) {
    ...
    this.setState({
      coordinates: <set your custom coordinates array here>,
      heading: <set your custom heading here>
    })
    ...
  }
}
```